# how to add a scrollable toolbar for pdf reader IOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, pdf-viewer, vfr-reader

I have downloaded the pdf reader from https://github.com/vfr/Reader. This looks great but the bottom page bar or toolbar is stable. It adds all the pages into one single tool bar with out providing any scrolling feature. could someone help me to change this to a scrollable view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by changing the readerpagebar to derive from UIScrollviewController instead of UIViewController and increased the content size of scroll bar to number of images mounted in it. if someone needs further info, I will post the code here.

Comment: Please post your code.I'm also trying to use "vfr".Please give detail description also.Thanks.